# SQL Running Stock Price

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to write a SQL query (SQL Server 2005) to calculate the current value of inventory on hand. I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID | QTY | BasePrice
1  | 10  | 100
2  | -2  | 0
3  | -2  | 0
4  | 10  | 200
5  | -2  | 0
```

Where qty > 0 is stock coming in and < 0 is stock going out. Negative quantities don't record a BasePrice due to other business rules. Base price is price per unit.

I need to find either the average price OR total price of inventory that is still on hand. So the resulting column needs to be:

```
ID | QTY | BasePrice | TotalPrice | AveragePrice
1  | 10  | 100       | 1000       | 100
2  | -2  | 0         | 800        | 100
3  | -2  | 0         | 600        | 100
4  | 10  | 200       | 2600       | 162.50
5  | -2  | 0         | 2275       | 162.50
```

I was able to work out this:

```
select  g1.projectionID,
        g1.qty, 
        g1.basePrice,
        ((sum(isnull(g2.basePrice,0)))) * sum(isnull(g2.Qty,0)) + (g1.Qty * (case when g1.Qty < 0 THEN (sum(isnull(g2.basePrice,0))) ELSE g1.BasePrice END)) As CurrenctValueOfStockOnHand


from test g1
left join test g2 on g2.projectionID < g1.projectionID
group by g1.ProjectionID, g1.Qty, g1.BasePrice
```

Which gives:

```
ID| QTY| BasePrice | TotalPrice
1 | 10 | 100.0000  | 1000.0000
2 | -2 | 0.0000    | 800.0000
3 | -2 | 0.0000    | 600.0000
4 | 10 | 200.0000  | 2600.0000
5 | -2 | 0.0000    | 4200.0000
```

But as you can see it gives the wrong values after the 2nd lot of inventory is added (after ID 4).

We currently have C# code that loops through each record and keeps a running total. For large stocks this takes far too long. If the only option is to use a cursor then we'll keep our C# code.

Comment: LAG function should help... although you dont show a very convincing order by value other than id...

Comment: That is one mighty confusing way to store data in SQL tables.

Comment: i agree - this would be alot easier with a better schema.  for example - there is no way to know which inventory value id 5 is taking

Comment: The ID here is just for simplicity. The full table has a date column that it will be ordered by. The date is some point in the future - we are projecting stock movements

Comment: @Randy - That's the point. It doesn't matter which stock they are taking, we want the average of the price of the stock that is left

Comment: is LAG available in SQL2005? I've never heard of it before and doing a quick Google search I can only find it in Oracle

Comment: I can't really answer your main question without using cursors, but it will help tremendously if you can calculate and save the `TotalPrice` as soon as you enter a record.

Comment: @rikitikitik the problem we have is that records could be inserted later that would re-order this table. In a previous comment I mentioned that the actual table has a date that we order by. Thats why we need to calculate it when we use it instead of storing it

Comment: @Greg so new records could be inserted in between existing records? That's nasty. Did you want just the final total, or the total at each record?

Comment: @rikitikitik it is nasty. It's all to do with out stock projections, so it's all in the future and subject to change. Unfortunately I need the total for each record, not just the final (although I still can't work out how to get the final without getting the value at each record).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After [Randy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318749) mentioned using LAG function I had a quick Google search for LAG function in SQL Server and found code using a table variable and an update statement.

```
declare @TempStocks TABLE (ProjectionID int, Qty Int, BasePrice Decimal (18,4), runningQty int, totalValueOfStockOnHand decimal(18,4))

insert into @TempStocks
select g1.*, sum(isnull(g2.Qty, 0)) + g1.Qty, 0
from gregTest g1
left join gregTest g2 on g2.projectionID < g1.ProjectionID
group by g1.ProjectionID, g1.BasePRice, g1.Qty

select * from @TempStocks

declare @CurrentValue Decimal (18,4)

set @CurrentValue = 0

update @TempStocks
set @CurrentValue = TotalValueOfStockOnHand = case when (Qty > 0) THEN (@CurrentValue + (BasePrice * Qty)) ELSE @CurrentValue + ((@CurrentValue / (RunningQty - qty) * Qty)) END

select *, TotalValueOfStockOnHand / RunningQty from @TempStocks
```

I'm still not convinced this is the best answer, but it does give the correct output without using a cursor